# The verb for something that became popular

Tags: single-word-requests

The verb for something that became popular (became a hit) when nobody expected it.

> Their first four movies have been quite obscure to the masses up until the release of the fifth one, which ______ (became a hit?) and became very popular.

Comment: 'Make it', 'make the mark', 'take off' are in the right area but don't sound as punchy as the antonym 'bomb'. 'Go viral' is perhaps better. But these only address your title question.

Comment: "... was the dark horse that unexpectedly/surprisingly turned out very popular." http://www.theidioms.com/dark-horse/  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dark%20horse

Comment: Does 'boomed' work?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite a single word, but a **sleeper hit** describes what you're looking for.

> In the entertainment industry, a sleeper hit is a title (such as a film, song or game) that becomes successful gradually, often with little promotion.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeper_hit)

Edit: Also, it's not a verb. :/

So here's a verb suggestion:
**exploded**

> Their first four movies have been quite obscure to the masses up until
>   the release of the fifth one, which **exploded** with popularity and
>   became a sleeper hit.

Comment: But we needed a verb!

Comment: Doh. Indeed we do!

Comment: See how I turned the tables. (My comment at OP).